# Cosmos DB stored procedure to scale RUs

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to write a stored procedure in Cosmos DB that will change the RUs for a container? I've been looking at the [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-javascript-query-api), but it mostly talks about working with documents, not collection metadata. It's easy enough to get the collection with

```
getContext().getCollection()
```

but from there I'm not sure what I can do with it to adjust collection metadata.

Can I write a stored procedure that will adjust the RUs? If so what does the code for that look like?

Comment: you can try this with azure function https://sajeetharan.com/2019/06/18/auto-scale-cosmosdb-with-azure-function-v2-0/

Comment: curious as to why you'd need this functionality ?

Comment: @AlexDrenea CosmosDB is billed by the hour, so I was going to write an Azure Logic App to scale it up and then scale it down after 59 minutes. Azure Logic Apps can run stored procedures. I was able to write an Azure Durable Function to accomplish this.

Comment: @scott-h That's what I though... You might not need a stored procedure for that though. You could easily write an azure function to resize a cosmos db collection via the SDK, or even a PowerShell script to use via the rest api. I've written a couple of articles on the subject on my blog if you want to take a look - https://alexdrenea.com/2019/06/28/scaling-an-azure-cosmos-db-instance-with-azure-automation/

Comment: Also,  just fiy, cosmosdb is charged by the hour but not for a continuous 60m interval. Billing is measured at the exact hour threshold do your scale down should happen at xx:59 ( 11:59) and not after 59 minutes becuase that might end up costing you the equivalent of 2 hours and not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the throughput via a stored procedure in Cosmos DB

Comment: Do you have any sources you can cite for this?

Comment: No, it just isn't part of the server side js API. You can see the full API code here: https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/DocDbWrapperScript.js.html There is no reference of the throughput or any update to it. It also makes sense since stored procedures in Cosmos can only be run against a logical partition which is a narrower scope of the collection itself so it wouldn't make sense to be possible via an SP.